# Will this AJAX refresh script overload my server?

Tags: jquery

I'm using this code to refresh a div every *5000 milliseconds*: (and update the title as well)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function changeTitle() {
   var title = $('.subjectContainer').html();
   document.title = title+' | WeeBuild Customer Support';
   }
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".subjectContainer").load("subject.php?ticket=<?php echo $_GET[ticket]; ?>");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $(".subjectContainer").load("subject.php?ticket=<?php echo $_GET[ticket]; ?>");
      changeTitle();
   }, 5000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
</script>
```

The page being loaded is just one line of text that is retrieved from the database.

See here: http://weebuild.heliohost.org/employee/subject.php?ticket=5156869

That's the page being loaded. When a user changes the subject of a ticket, I am making it stay updated so it will change for everyone viewing the ticket without refreshing the page.

But, will this overload the server I'm on?

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing the specifics of your server.

Comment: Well, would that number of requests overload a server to begin with?

Comment: A better way to approach it would be to bind events to the ticket subject changing and then only doing the ajax call OR you could still run the code every 5 seconds but run a test to see if the ticket has changed and then only if the subject has changed do you load from the server.

Comment: @Aknosis So do you mean only refresh the div if the subject has changed? That would be a good idea and what I was trying to figure out earlier, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @Nathan yes, the easiest way to do this would be storing the title in $(".subjectContainer").data('currentTitle') - now that it is stored somewhere you can reference that when you check to see if it has changed or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of constantly polling your server, which will indeed introduce a lot of overhead, look into long polling instead. From your code it looks like you are just trying to update the status of a help ticket - which I assume doesn't happen every five seconds. Long polling basically sends a data request out to the server which can then respond at its leisure. Giving you the convenience of only updating when something actually changed. And also not pinging your server incessantly.

Comment: Great idea, but how do I make it only update if the subject has changed? I will probably change it to every 5 or 10 minutes or longer. It would be great if I could make it only refresh if the subject actually has changed.

Comment: By handling it server side. Client sends request for updated subject along with a really long time out time. Server gets the request and just holds onto it (in db, wherever you want). Then when the subject actually updates finally send your response back. If the response times out on client end then just resubmit it.

Comment: Seems like a lot of work lol. I just changed it to every 5 minutes. Do you think that is good? I'm sure that wouldn't overload the server.

Comment: If you are sure it wouldn't then why did you ask if it would =). I think that because swapping out your current method with long polling wouldn't be that difficult you should continue as is. If your server gets tied up you could always extend the polling period or swap in long polling. But if you have time - do it the best way from the start.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to make sure :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on following factors:

1. Simultaneous users on your site
2. Database query time
3. Amount of data loading

If any of these is high with respect to your server capacity. It will overload.

Way to measure capacity is benchmarking. (use apache benchmark `ab` or others)

Way to prevent overloading is caching.

Comment: Thanks. I am just making it update every 5 minutes now, which I'm sure wouldn't cause an overload.